# How to list all users and groups on Linux?

Tags: linux

How to list all users and groups on Linux?

And what's the difference between `user:root` and `user:othergroup`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`getent(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getent)

`user:root` is a combination of user `user` and group `root`. `user:othergroup` is a combination of user `user` and group `othergroup`.

Answer (score 0):

From the commandline, simply look at the files `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`. The information you look for is in the first column.

Comment: This will fail if something like LDAP is being used.

Comment: Worse, this will *appear* to work but will fail to show any accounts or groups that are not present in those files.

Comment: Agreed :-) I'm starting to feel my age ;-)

Comment: If you have LDAP, looking at those files will not get all groups, on those cases, command "getent group" will.