# Determine all users on the Linux machine

Tags: linux, unix, shell, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to list all users and groups on linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/140105/how-to-list-all-users-and-groups-on-linux)

How to determine all the users on a Linux machine (not only the ones who are logged in)?

I searched and found the following command:

`$ cat /etc/passwd | grep "/home" | cut -d: -f1`

But my concern is that I could not find `root` in the output of above command. Also when I try `who` command I get the same response when I am logged in a `root` and as a normal user. Please help!

Comment: You've specified additional information for your question in the comments. Please update your question to include these points.

Answer (score 4):

your command wont find root because root's home is /root not /home/[user] also, it wont show remote network accounts.

a better command is `getent passwd | cut -d ":" -f1`.

Comment: But what about the `who` command? When I am logged into as `sam` user then it shows output `sam`. When I am logged into as `root` then also it shows `sam`.

Comment: refer to "man who" for more info. Shows logged in users, not all users. re your query, did you log in as sam and then run su/sudo, or did you go directly as root from login prompt. Also if you are logged in as sam else where (like anouther window) itll show up

Comment: `getent` is the right way to check the user database.

Comment: Sirex: I want to login as a account which is having /bin/false shell. How can I do it? Is there any way to do it?

Comment: this is nearly always a bad idea. However you can do it by changing the shell to be /bin/bash and setting a password on the account. In all seriousness though, the need to do this is a good indication of a case of "you're doing it wrong"

Answer (score 2):

Because $HOME folder for root is `/root`, not in `/home`.

To list all the 'real' users have shell (assumming is `/bin/bash`), you can use:

```
grep "/bin/bash" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: Ohh..ok. But what about the `who` command? When I am logged into as `sam` user then it shows sam. When I am logged into as `root` then also it shows sam.

Comment: Please give us the output of `who` and `egrep 'root|sam' /etc/passwd`?

Comment: Output of `egrep`: root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin

Comment: Output of 'who': sam pts/0        Sep 11 23:01 <ip address>

Answer (score 2):

Take the search (grep) out and cut at the first semi-colon: `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1`

Comment: It lists many many things like: `operator, games, gopher, ftp, dbus, vcsa`. All of them are users?

Comment: Yes, they are users. Many are created by the OS/applications on install. Have a look at `cat /etc/passwd`

Comment: yes, but unless they have a shell in them like /bin/bash they cant log in. typically the shell is set to /bin/false for these "service accounts".

Comment: ok, to exclude /bin/false, use `cat /etc/passwd | grep -v "/bin/false" | cut -d: -f1` To only include /bin/bash use `cat /etc/passwd | grep "/bin/bash" | cut -d: -f1`

Comment: Sirex: I want to login as a account which is having /bin/false shell. How can I do it? Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Login as root and `su - <user> -s /bin/bash`.